# Client not sending all data before disconnecting

Tags: c#, client-server

I'm currently working on a server/client and the basics are almost done. But I'm having a problem with sending data after closing and opening the test client program.

This is how my disconnect method looks like:

```
public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (m_clientSocket != null)
        {
            m_clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Receive);
        }
    }
```

And the test data looks like this:

```
Client cl = new Client(888, "127.0.0.1");
        cl.Connect(null);
        cl.DataArrived += MyListenerMethod;
        cl.Disconnect();

        cl.Connect("hello");
        cl.SendData("hello2");
```

Now the problem is it will send "hello" and "hello2" sometimes and sometimes just "hello" when  I close and start the client program repeatedly. 
I'm pretty sure that this is working according to design but I want all data sent before the program terminates, I'm guessing that I have to use delays or something along those lines to achieve this. I know this may seem like a trivial question but I'm wondering if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the socket is buffering the data to be sent, but isn't flushing the socket when its shut down.  The result is that if you attempt to shut down the socket too soon the buffered data is never sent.

According to this blog article you may have more luck with the `NetworkStream` class.

- [Flush Socket in .NET or C#](http://angrez.blogspot.com/2007/02/flush-socket-in-net-or-c.html)

(Alternatively use WCF or .Net remoting and have it deal with all this messy stuff)

Comment: So the problem is that I'm using good old String instead of NetworkStream to relay messages?

Comment: @Siemsen The problem is that the socket isn't being flushed - my guess was that `m_clientSocket` is an instance of `Socket`, but I couldn't find any information on how to flush a socket in the documentation.